# Connections to two Oracle Databases using TNS with different authentication methods (Python, cx_Oracle)

Tags: python-3.x, oracle, cx-oracle, tnsnames, tns

I have to maintain connections to two Oracle databases (12c, Python 3.5, cx_Oracle 6.0.3, Oracle drivers 12.1.0) in parallel (one database uses Kerberised authentication and the other doesn't).

I have created two separate TNS configuration folders (with their separate `sqlnet.ora` and `tnsnames.ora`) and attempted the following:

```py
import cx_Oracle
import os

os.environ['TNS_ADMIN'] = r'D:\tns\settings1'  # settings folder for first connection
with cx_Oracle.connect("", "", "DB1") as con:  # uses kerberos
    cursor = con.cursor()
    ret = cursor.execute("SELECT 'HELLO WORLD FROM DATABASE1!' AS msg FROM DUAL")
    for entry in cursor:
        print(entry[0])

os.environ['TNS_ADMIN'] = r'D:\tns\settings2'  # settings folder for second connection
with cx_Oracle.connect("username", "password", "DB2") as con:
    cursor = con.cursor()
    ret = cursor.execute("SELECT 'HELLO WORLD FROM DATABASE2!' AS msg FROM DUAL")
    for entry in cursor:
        print(entry[0])
```

While I am able to establish connections from two separate processes in isolation, above fails when executed in a single script from one process (I am getting a "`ORA-12631: Username retrieval failed`"-error which indicates that the `sqlnet.ora`-settings from `D:\tns\settings1` are still being used to establish the second connection).

My `sqlnet.ora` in `D:\tns\settings2` unsets all Kerberos-related values set in `D:\tns\settings2\sqlnet.ora`:

```
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES = (NONE)
NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH = (TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT)
SQLNET.KERBEROS5_CC_NAME = NONE
SQLNET.KERBEROS5_CONF = NONE
SQLNET.KERBEROS5_CONF_MIT = NONE
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_KERBEROS5_SERVICE = NONE
```

Again - in isolation both connections succeed (and TNS-settings are picked up correctly from their respective folders `TNS_ADMIN` points to).

Any ideas how to get this to work?

Comment: 'fails' isn't very descriptive - it would be helpful to include the output/error(s) you get in your question.

Comment: added additional details - the concrete error message just indicates that the second connection still relies on sqlnet.ora from the settings1-folder.